# Basic information extraction from html?

Tags: html, parsing, extract, information-extraction

I have a project where users submit many links to external sites and I need to parse the HTML of these submitted links and extract basic information from the page in the same way that Digg and Facebook do when a link is submitted.

I want to retrieve:

1. main title or heading (could be in title, `h1`, `h2`, `p` etc...)
2. intro or description text (could be in `div`, `p` etc...)
3. main image

My main problem is that there seem to be too many options to explore here and im getting a little confused to sat the least. Many solutions I have looked so far seem to be inadequate or huge overkill.

Comment: tl;dr: use html parsing library with xpath.

Answer (score 2):

You would pick a server side language to do this.

For example, with PHP, you could use `get_meta_tags()` for the meta tags...

```
$meta = get_meta_tags('http://google.com');
```

And you could use DOMDocument to get the `title` element (some may argue if needing the `title` element, you may as well use DOMDocument to get the meta tags as well).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML('http://google.com');

$title = $dom
           ->getElementsByTagName('head')
           ->item(0)
           ->getElementsByTagName('title')
           ->item(0)
           ->nodeValue;
```

As for getting *main image*, that would require some sort of extraction of what may be considered the main image. You could get all `img` elements and look for the largest one on the page.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML('http://google.com');

$imgs = $dom
         ->getElementsByTagName('body')
         ->item(0)
         ->getElementsByTagName('img');

$imageSizes = array();

foreach($imgs as $img) {

  if ( ! $img->hasAttribute('src')) {
     continue;
  }

  $src = $img->getAttribute('src');

  // May need to prepend relative path
  // Assuming Apache, http and port 80

  $relativePath = rtrim($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') . '/';

  if (substr($src, 0, strlen($relativePath) !== $relativePath) {
     $src = $relativePath . $src;
  }

  $imageInfo = getimageinfo($src);

  if ( ! $imageInfo) {
     continue;
  }    

  list($width, $height) = $imageInfo;

  $imageSizes[$width * $height] = $img;

}

$mainImage = end($imageSizes);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply alex. unfortunately alot of the time web pages dont have the information i need in meta tags. often sites will have the same description tag on all sub pages and are not specific to a page.

Comment: the idea of using the image size is a good one. i was also thinking if you had several images of the same or similar size it would be a fairly high likelihood of the first one being the main image

Comment: @sam Yep, it is hard to choose what the *main image* is.